# Hard to debug situation (or bug) in Opera

Tags: javascript, html, dom, opera

Ok, I'll do my best.

There's this page http://tiu.ru/image/tmp/test_2.html , which looks differently in Opera then in Chrome and Firefox (maybe others).

It evaluates a javascript code inside `<div></div>`, that does `document.write("")` of a piece of another HTML code with `<script>`, that evaluates JS code that asks Google Ads to write ads.

Google Ads writes it's container and container's content (which loads advertising from Yandex) ((maybe you'll need to disable adblock to see ads, but you can just view the screenshot)).

And the problem is that in Opera it writes that content outside the original div somehow.

Screenshot of result for Chrome: [image]
Screenshot of result for Opera: [image]

If you take that code inside `document.write()` and put it just as usual HTML code -- everything works well. See http://tiu.ru/image/tmp/test_3.html

I can't figure out how to debug that google ads code, that's why I ask for help. Thank you.

p.s.: you can save page to localhost somewhere and open it, ads won't be loaded, but DOM tree will be the same wrong.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Well, `document.write()` is so awful that I'm not surprised it causes such a problem.  Probably the issue is that the browser creates the outer `<div>` **before** it executes the script block.  That seems completely reasonable, though I can also imagine a browser deciding to do that differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you add a script tag with document.write() that does document.write() to add the one that calls GA_googleFillSlot, which itself does document.write() to add a SCRIPT with SRC set to a doubleclick.net URL which calls back into google_ads.js to trigger another document.write() that adds an inline SCRIPT containing another document.write()  call to add another external script, this time loading context.js from an.yandex.ru, and it looks like context.js also contains code to add yet two more external scripts to the document. But at this point the damage already happened: although a loading external script inserted with document.write() should block parsing, something odd happens when the doubleclick.net script loads and calls back into google_ads.js that makes Opera close the parent DIV.

Let's see what the DOM looks like the moment DoubleClick calls back to google_ads - by setting a breakpoint in GA_googleSetAdContentsBySlotForSync and using Opera Dragonfly. There we go: on entering this script, the DOM is still OK, the DIV is not closed - but when this script thread does document.write() to add `<div id=google_ads_div_ru__context_informers_addon_360x90_ad_container>` with comments, markup and scripts inside, something about that new content makes Opera believe it needs to close the former document.write()-inserted DIV. It's a parsing bug deep inside the handling of multiple nested document.write()s, I guess.

This will work fine with Opera's upcoming HTML5 parser. If at all possible for you, don't worry about it and wait until Opera 12 sorts it all out.

Comment: Well, that sounds like true explanation, so let it be an answer for now (maybe the blamer is document.writing of div, I'll need to test that). Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Opera has a strict XHTML parser. Try wrapping your javascript in CDATA tags so the parser will ignore the `<` and `&` characters as well as any other illegal characters in your script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */

  // put your js code here

/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, that actually solved the problem! You saved the day (two days, actually). Thanks!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was mistaken. It doesn't solve the problem. Here's example http://tiu.ru/image/tmp/test_4.html and btw in original HTML I actually load script from outside, so there's no need in CDATA. I just was too much about that bug yesterday and tired, so I thought it was solved))